# React router routes not working

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have 2 basic routes like this:

```jsx
<Route name="app" path="/" handler={Home}>
    <Route name="profile" path="profile" handler={Profile}/>
</Route>
```

Now, I want the default page ( mysite.com/page ) to just show the Home Component.

And when I browse to mysite.com/page#/profile , I want it to just show the Profile component.

However, both URLs just show the 'Home' component. And the Profile component is never seen.

Any clue as to what I have misconfigured? ( there are no errors in the console )

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried surrounding `Route` with `Router`  :

```
var Router = require('react-router');

var DefaultRoute = Router.DefaultRoute,
    Link = Router.Link,
    Route = Router.Route,
```

then...

```
<Router history={history}>
    <Route component={App}>
      <Route name="app" path="/" handler={Home}>
      <Route name="profile" path="profile" handler={Profile}/>
      <DefaultRoute handler={Home}/>
    </Route>
  </Router>
```

check this link [here](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/examples/master-detail/app.js)